# User Management Question

Tags: users

I realize the title of the post probably made everyone roll their eyes...but bear with me...please.

I need some very advanced user management where some users can be assigned as the admin of a group that can add users to that group, make sub groups and assign admins to it to add users...all the users need to have permissions to add edit and view some info that will be part of a large module I am creating...but unique to each user/subuser.

I think Organic groups, but I don't need, or want the content management/viewing aspects, just strictly user management and permissions, but permissions being restricted only to allowed permissions within my specific module...not system wide permissions...

I am looking for a slimmer solution than Organic groups, if possible.

Thoughts? Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

What I am seeing here is an entity with a bunch of other entity reference fields.
This followed by a bunch of access permission settings.

> some users can be assigned as the admin of a group that can add users to that group

Create a "group" entity that has 2 entity references fields (multivalue) one for users and one for admins. Each referencing the users and the admins who can have privileges.

> make sub groups and assign admins to it to add users...

Add another entity reference field to reference the same group entity type as the parent

> all the users need to have permissions to add edit and view some info that will be part of a large module I am creating...but unique to each user/subuser.

You would just need to play around the access control for that particular entity using a module like https://drupal.org/project/content_access or other ACL modules